# How to base64 encode/decode a .wav file in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, base64

I need to base64 **encode AND decode** a .wav file.

**Why I want to do this:**
I'm in a situation where I cannot include a .wav file in the app bundle (*developing a standard library and don't want to go the route of the ['real' or 'universal' framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework)*). So I need to store my sound file in memory as an NSString and turn it into sound as needed.

**The answers I hope to receive:**
(1) How to generate a base64 string (NSString) representation of a small .wav file.
(2) How to decode this string and somehow play it with native Audio services.

Thank you in advance guys/gals.

Comment: Did you have a look at the Base64-related methods of NSData ?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by reading the wav into a C array with an ExtAudioFileRef.  Have a look at ExtendedAudioFile.h in the  framework. After you have your audio in a C array You could use NSData to serialize/deserialize it.

Comment: Or even easier, simply load the `wav` file directly into an `NSData` instance.